# How to write string to .txt file in C++ using FILE

Tags: c++

I have `string str = "6.5.1"`
I want to write `str` to file .txt, but the result is `��j`
Here my code

```
FILE *outfile = fopen("solution.txt", "w");
string test = "6.5.1";
fprintf(outfile, "%s\n", test);
```

I use `string, FILE` because I want to pass `FILE` as an argument, and convert `string` from another file to method.

How can I fix this problem?
Thanks.

p\s: sorry, tag is `c++` not `c`

Comment: What type is `string`

Comment: What is the real type of `string`? Is it a `char*`?

Comment: Are you using the CS50 library?

Comment: 'C' does not have `method`s... You have to be more explicit in what it is you are trying to achieve and how.

Comment: No points for pointing out the obvious... Such is life... :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You clarified that you needed a c++ solution and required to use `FILE *`:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>

int main(void) {
    FILE *outfile = std::fopen("solution.txt", "w");
    std::string test = "6.5.1";
    std::fprintf(outfile, "%s\n", test.c_str());
    std::fclose(outfile);
}
```

Comment: Worth explaining that C doesn't have a `string` type and that the code he has likely was pulled from a CS50 example that uses the `typedef` you show (which can confuse the hell out of new C programmers) ... and a glaring example for [Is it a good idea to **typedef** pointers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers) (hint: Answer - No).

Comment: my bad, tag is ```c++``` Sorry

Comment: You're writing c code.  Do you need a c++ solution instead?

Comment: yes, i don't pass ```ofstream``` as argument, so that  I need using ```FILE```

Comment: Updated answer as requested.

Comment: i update here, it's right?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are asking.